# getFilesDir() でローカルに保存した HTML ファイルが動きません

Tags: android, javascript, css, html

どなたかご助力下さい。

`getFilesDir()` で、 `data/data/パッケージ名/Files/○○○` の下に

- css フォルダ
- javascript フォルダ
- 画像フォルダ
- html ファイル

を配置しています。

※ これらは HTML 経由で ZIP ファイルをダウンロード後、こちらに解凍しております。

この HTML ファイルを `WebView` の `loadURL` で読み込ませたところ、 JavaScript や CSS は反応しませんでした。

※ HTML に記述済みのコードは実行されています。

JavaScript や CSS を使うにはどうしたらよろしいでしょうか？

何卒、宜しくお願い致します。

追記 2016/2/4

ご回答頂いた皆様ありがとうございます。

JavaScripte 側で JQuery を使用しておりまして、
その JQuery の Ajax が原因で読み込みが出来ていないようでした。

そこで、 .setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs() を使用し表示することは出来ました。

皆様の知恵をお貸し頂き大変助かりました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: loadURLはどのように呼んでますか？（確かいくつか呼び方があったはずなので

Comment: webView.loadUrl("file:///data/data/パッケージ名/files/○○○/□□□.html");
と記述しております。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 「これらはHTML経由でZIPファイルをダウンロード後、こちらに解凍」というのは、本来はWebサーバ上に配置されアクセス可能だったファイル一式を端末内にダウンロードしているという意味でしょうか？この場合、例えばHTML内に書かれているCSSファイルへのURLはそのまま（外部URL）という事になっていませんか？

Comment: 分かりにくくて申し訳ございません。
サーバー側はダウンロード専用で、
HTMLファイル内のリンクに関する記述も相対的に記述しております。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

再現しませんでした。
下記を実行すると、cssが適用されました。

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.io.*;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private File file;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.webView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //テスト用のhtml,cssをファイルに保存
        this.file = writeToFile("samplehtml.html", "hello world");
        writeToFile("samplecss.css", "body{color:#FF0000}");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("sample", "htmlfile = " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        this.webView.loadUrl("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    private File writeToFile(String fileName, String content) {
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            final FileOutputStream out = this.openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
            writer.append(content);
            return this.getFileStreamPath(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if(writer!=null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

logcat出力

> com.example.myapp D/sample﹕htmlfile = /data/data/com.example.myapp/files/samplehtml.html

画面
[image: htmlからリンクしたcssが効いてテキストが赤くなってるの図]

Answer (score 0):

実装を見ていないので何とも言えませんが、使用しているWebViewに対して、
Javascriptの有効化を行っているでしょうか。

> webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);